# Each loop with a condition that current loop doesn't match the previous

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller like this:

products_controller.rb

```
def index
@products = Product..where('order_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all

#[id, order_date, name, category]
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<thead>
 <th>
   <%= product.category %>
 </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <%= product.name %>
 </tr>
</tbody>

# This code loop through each product to display its product category and the product name.
```

How can I define a condition so that if `product.category` is equal to the previous `product.category`, then just append the `product.name` to `<tbody>`?

Comment: What about if `product.category` is not the same as `the previous category` but the same as `one of the previous categories`? If this also applies, then you can try grouping the products by category, directly from your query, so that what you just need to do in the view is loop through the categories.

Comment: The condition only applies on `the previous category`, so grouping doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Hmm... Another way, in this case, is to prepare the data from the controller. You can have a private method in your controller that loops through your `@products` and groups any with the same category as the previous/next together... I think this can work, but I'm not sure about how optimal it will be.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try!

Comment: If you want, I can draft something out, but I think you already got it? :)...

Comment: Yup I got it, thanks!